# What is inside the Technic Powered Up XL motor?

Tags: piece-information, motor, electronics, powered-up, disassembly

What components are inside the new Technic Powered Up XL motor? Is it the same as the PF XL motor, except with a different connector?

[image: XL Motor]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was curious about this, and TLG was willing to provide me with one of these motors, so I opened it up. I was able to get the outer shell off by cutting down the 4 tabs on the outside. This motor does not appear to be meant to be opened and put back together. These tabs hold it together very firmly and I wasn't able to move them out of the way without damaging them. The motor does not stay together properly without them.

[image: XL Motor open]

The light bluish gray front can also be removed from the motor to reveal the internals.

[image: 3 sections]

We can see that it uses a double set of planetary gears that are very similar to the PF XL motor.

[image: gears]

We can see an additional chip under the drive axle that is not present in PF motors. I believe that this is a rotary encoder to allow the motor to rotate in fixed increments.

[image: Rotary encoder]

There is a black ring around the red drive axle that is magnetic.

[image: Drive axle with black ring]

For comparison, here is an image from another teardown of the PF XL motor:

[image: PF XL motor]

We can see that the internal motor and gearing is roughly the same, but the PF version does not include the rotary encoder.

Comment: The horror, the horror!

Comment: In my experience, the PUP motor spins at ~2x the speed and ~1/2 the torque, compared to the PF motors (a pretty big improvement IMO).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Not sure how this could be an improvement. PU XL and L motors have pretty much the same specs now (apart from size), unlike with PF. What you were looking for in PF series is L motor. Higher torque and slower rpm has its own applications.

Comment: Do you happen to have a picture of black ring you've mentioned? Does PU version use same electrical motor as PF one?

Comment: @Alex I've added a photo of the output axle with the black ring that I mentioned. The internal motors appear the same to me, but I don't have a PF XL to compare against.

Comment: @Alex The PF XL motor was more powerful the PF L motor, when geared to similar speeds, so I tend to use it more than the L motor. I rarely used the XL without some gearing up though, which is why I consider the faster speed of the PUP version an improvement.