# What is inside the LEGO Powered Up L motor?

Tags: piece-information, motor, electronics, powered-up, disassembly

What's inside the Powered Up L motor (part [bb0959c01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0959c01))?

[image: Part photo]

How do its internals compare to the [XL motor](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15031/what-is-inside-the-technic-powered-up-xl-motor) and the [M motor](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10367/what-is-inside-the-lego-powered-up-m-motor)?

Comment: Just to be clear - do you mean [set 88013](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/technic-large-motor-88013), or something different?

Comment: Closely related: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15031/what-is-inside-the-technic-powered-up-xl-motor and https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15031/what-is-inside-the-technic-powered-up-xl-motor

Comment: The motor from the off-road buggy

Comment: @IvanSanchez your two links are the same, was that a copy-paste error? For reference, most probably [this](https://brickset.com/sets/42124-1/Off-Road-Buggy) is the set in question, which has two of [Electric, Motor Powered Up, L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0959c01#T=C).

Comment: @zovits Indeed, I screwed up. I took the liberty of editing the question; should be clearer now with some links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This motor was not easy to take apart. Unlike some of the others that have screws or clips that can be released, I wasn't able to get into this one without basically cutting it in half. If you need to repair one of these, it is possible to get it apart and put it back together, but I believe that glue would need to be involved to hold it securely together again.

Here's what it looks like once you get the front cover off:

[image: cover off]

This is very similar internally to the [linear motor](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10367/what-is-inside-the-lego-powered-up-m-motor), but the internal gearbox is longer to accommodate the rotation sensor.

Here it is from the top:

[image: cover off top]

Here's a shot from the bottom showing the board:

[image: board shot]

We can see similar control circuitry to other PU motors with rotation sensors. Here's what the board looks like from the top with the gearbox removed:

[image: gearbox removed]

The visible chip interacts with the black ring in the gearbox to sense rotation.

The gearbox itself is a double planetary system similar to what is found in other motors:

[image: gears]

[image: gears]

Here's the final output with the black ring that interacts with the sensor:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks you so mush, and last thing is this a 130 motor ou it's bigger

Comment: @Jacob It looks like a standard 130 to me, but I don't know enough about DC motors to know for sure that it isn't some other similar motor.

Comment: I mean the standard 130 is bigger than the generic toy motors.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a related video: [What is inside a Powered Up Large Motor](https://youtu.be/3nyhcw9Ye1g)

The video shows how the motor is being opened. There are no screws or tabs to do this. So, I have to use a knife and a Philips screwdriver. The result is - the cover of the motor was damaged and broken.

The objective of this mission was to check what is wrong with the motor since it could not be detected by the Powered Up control/battery hub.

But then, I found out all the parts or components were in order - the soldering was OK, and nothing unusual with the connectivity and features.

So, my guess is- the circuit or chip on the PCB is faulty. This is beyond the capability of people without electronic knowledge (like me) to handle it.

Thus, the overall objective of this video is to show what is inside the Large Powered Up motor.

Interesting to note that, there are 2 planetary gears and a rotation sensor. This is why this motor can provide data on its orientation.

[image: The rotation sensor]

This is the photo of the motor - [image: manufactured by company called Hoi Po]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to expand your answer!