# How do I disassemble Powered Up Motor XL?

Tags: technic, motor, repair, powered-up

My question is, how do you take the XL motor apart?
I tried with my knife and hands, but unfortunately, it is still whole in one piece (tabs).

I got the [XL motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0960c01&idColor=85#T=C&C=85) from the set [42099](https://brickset.com/sets/42099-1/4x4-X-Treme-Off-Roader) and I would to make the set again if it wasn't stuck.

I want to open the motor so I can see what's wrong with it; I think it is actually a broken motor.

Comment: What does the motor do or not do that makes you think that it is broken?

Comment: Also see https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/15031/3498